# The most efficient and painless way to gain weight

Tags: nutrition, weight-gain

I am 187cm (in between 6'1 and 6'2 feet, i suppose) tall and weigh 61 kg.
I understand that I am way too skinny and I need to gain weight in a some way.

My relatives insist on eating more rich in fat foods with a lot of oil, like fried potato, or pieces of pork, with rather a high concentration of fat. Even not very large amount (in terms of net weight) of these foods is supposed to be beneficial for weight gain. However, I feel that I digest this kind of food rather hardly and painfully. After a dinner, the whole remaining day I suffer from burps and feel nasty smack.

Another proposal is to eat more snacks, cookies, and some junk stuff like that. I can be helpful in terms of weight gain, but due to the improper balance in nutritious elements would lead to another kind of health issues later.

My question is : how would look like a healthier and more easy to digest way to gain weight look like? Which strategy - frequency of meals, kind of products are good for such a goal, those, that would, on one hand, contain large enough amount of calories in rather small serving, and, on the other hand, not spoil balance in terms of nutritious elements?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't think in terms of just "gaining weight" but instead "gaining lean mass" - I'm sure you do not want to just be obese! Besides, there are many questions in the site referring to weight gain and exercise, you should take a look at those too.